# I need a correction in my Naive Bayes Visualization

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, matplotlib, machine-learning

I built a Naive Bayes Model and i am having problem with the Visualization as it is showing me an Error ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (60000,2) (533,) 
two is just a sample with 22 variables with two output observation

```
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
X_set, y_set = X_train, y_train
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
                     np.arange(start = X_set[:, 1].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 1].max() + 1, step = 0.01))
plt.contourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape),
             alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(('red', 'green')))
plt.xlim(X1.min(), X1.max())
plt.ylim(X2.min(), X2.max())
for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
    plt.scatter(X_set[y_set == j, 0], X_set[y_set == j, 1],
                c = ListedColormap(('red', 'green'))(i), label = j)
plt.title('Classifier (Training set)')
plt.xlabel('xxx')
plt.ylabel('xxxxxx')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

My error now is from this line

```
plt.contourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape)
```

The message is : 
 ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (92600,2) (533,)

the x1,x2 where my results after performing the np.meshgrid operation and their shapes. The same thing applies to the x_train and x_test. I made the x_set just because i could perform the same thing again and make a general code

A little history about my data:
i am working with texts data classification with a supervised Machine learning model- so i drew out this test sample and created a document term matrix for my model. did the predictions but i just want to make a visualization.

Please if there is also any suggestions on any other way to visualize ill be more than pleased

i also applied the KPCA and used 2 main components. it also threw and error

```
 plt.scatter(X_set[y_set == j, 0], X_set[y_set == j, 1],

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

here is the sample code from creating the bag of words model

```
# Creating the Bag of Words model
#countvectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_features = 1500)
#the corpus is an array list of processed texts with each row containing alphabeths
#total array length 22 
data_Vectorizer = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
#data_dtm now transformed into an array of length 22 and 533 columns
data_dtm = DataFrame(data_Vectorizer.toarray(),columns = vectorizer.get_feature_names())
#the x is an array with numbers either 0 or 1  with length 22,1 column
y = x 


# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data_dtm, y, test_size = 0.20, random_state = 0)
#Xtrain (17,533)
#Xtest (5,533)
#ytrain (17,1)
#ytest (5,1)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

from sklearn.decomposition import KernelPCA
kpca = KernelPCA(n_components = 2, kernel = 'rbf')
X_train = kpca.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = kpca.transform(X_test)


# Fitting Naive Bayes to the Training set with GaussianNB
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
classifier = GaussianNB()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

# Making the Confusion Matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```

Comment: Could you tell which line in your code is causing the error? Also, could you clarify what is this `x1 (200,300), x2 (200,300), x_set (17,533), x_test (5,533), x_train (17,533)`?

Comment: @Raghuram I edited the question i hope the explaination clarified your question and if not, please let me know thank you.

Comment: What are the shapes of X_set and y_set? I would like to test your code locally, but as some variables definitions are missing from the code you posted, I am unable to do that.

Comment: X_set and y_set has the same shape of X_train and y_train (Xtrain (17,533), ytrain (17,1)).. i made an update again to show the history